# No water to toilet after the city purged hydrants

Tags: plumbing, toilet

The city was opening fire hydrants around the neighborhood resulting in no water coming to the house. This happened while I was at work. When I came home I had to turn the faucets and showers on to release air in the lines.

Everything works except for the upstairs toilet. It is not the fill valve inside the toilet, There is no water coming to the toilet from the plumbing.

I have disconnected the line and no water is coming out.
The sink gets water upstairs.

What are the possible reasons for this?

Comment: Some kind of blockage at a restriction or valve.  Probably from the sink to toilet.  Shut off main water valve, leave upstairs faucet open and open a downstairs faucet. close all faucets except toilet(connected back) and turn on main.  Should have two people.

Comment: Is it possible someone was messing with the valves downstairs in an attempt to get the water to flow again?  A lot of people don't know "lefty loosy righty tighty"...

Answer (score 2):

If the first comment doesn't work and there is a speedy valve below the toilet;
with two people-

- first turn off main water valve.
- Open cold water faucet in the affected bath to release the water pressure then close it gently.
- With a small bucket at hand, remove the bonnet (valve handle has to be neither all open nor all closed) off the toilet speedy valve
- then have the 2nd person open the main valve *slightly* to purge the toilet line while catching the water in the bucket.
- Reassemble bonnet onto valve,
- open main valve slowly and test for flow at toilet. Make sure you left the toilet valve in the open position.

Speedy valve:

[image]